# Issues with Full Splash Screen in Flutter: Black Status Bar and Blank White Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, splash-screen

I'm currently implementing a full splash screen in my Flutter app, but I'm facing two main issues:

**Black Status Bar:** When I try to hide the status bar using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]), it results in a full black status bar. How can I properly hide the status bar while maintaining the correct appearance of my app's content?

Current Splash Screen View : -

[image]

**Blank White Screen Before Splash Screen:** When launching the app, I notice a brief blank white screen appearing before the splash screen is shown. This causes an unpleasant user experience. How can I eliminate this blank white screen and display the splash screen immediately upon app launch?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// SplashScreen widget
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "R",
              style: GoogleFonts.notoSerif(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontSize: 120,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 36),
            Text(
              "ReviZ",
              style: GoogleFonts.notoSerif(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontSize: 36,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling it from my below main.dart code

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
  
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
  
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ReviZ',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: dimBlue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // Ensure that the state is kept alive
    return Builder(
      ////
      },
    );
  }




 }
```